# Could not run build action using Gradle distribution / all gms/firebase libraries must be exact the same

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

After Updating my gradle-version to 3.3.1 and my google-services-version to 4.2.0, I'm getting the following error while building:

```
Error:Internal error:
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
```

My build-gradle-project-file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build-module-gradle-file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters '--utf16'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX.XXXX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 140
        versionName "14.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/amazon-mobile-associates-1.0.73.0.jar')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"


    implementation 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:1.0.0-beta5'
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    //
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'

    //compile 'com.appnext.sdk:native-ads2:2.+' // New Native Ads
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

I tried to delete the user-gradle-directory and the project-gradle-directory and relaunch android studio without any help. I tried to invalidate cache / restart, as well, but nothing helped.

I also can't fix the issue (all gms/firebase libraries must be exact the same...). And I realize that in all of my files the "package.R" is not recognized any more.

I have no clue to fix these problems.

It would be great if someone could help me or give me an idea.

Comment: I have also faced the same issue, did you fix it?